# Unable to show color fill animation in div when the page loads

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-waypoints

```js
$("#whoami").waypoint(function() {
    console.log('you have scrolled to the h1!');
   });
```

```css
.d8{
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2.5rem;
    margin-left: 5rem;
    border-radius: 1rem;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #e74c3c 85%, #FFF 50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="d8"></div>
```

Now I have been trying to fill the color in the div when the waypoint reaches the particular section having some nice animation effect for the user and I am not able to achieve it though,
Have tried transition effect and keyframe none seems to work, any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: your code is missing but the issue is clear .. you cannot animate linear-gradient,

Comment: its the waypoint showing the error, i included to show what i want to achieve finally, and as you said we cant animate, what could be the possible solution. any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In you case you can animate `background-size` instead of `background-image` ([that you cannot animate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties)) and make the `linear-gradient` to be one color as the white part will be the part without background:

```css
.d8 {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 80%;
  height: 2.5rem;
  margin-left: 5rem;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #e74c3c, #e74c3c);
  background-size: 80% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.d8:hover {
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="d8"></div>
```

Comment: Yes, I can, thanks , thats very clever...trying it.(m a newbie)